# What is bonus EXP?

Tags: diablo-iii

As the title states, I am curious as to what bonus exp is in the game.

I read that there are different bonuses for killing monsters higher and lower than your current level. What are the ranges/bonuses?

Does this also affect how much gold/items that are dropped?

On the flip side, are the penalties as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few bonus experience awards for

- Destruction,
- Mighty Blow,
- Massacre,
- Pulverized, and
- another awarded when dipping below 10% health at the end of a fight (Survival?)

The more you kill/do, or lower you end up, the higher the awards.

Comment: These awards are received through "chaining". As soon as you kill/destroy something it starts a short timer (seems to be 3 or so  seconds). If you do it again (kill something again, smash something again), it will count to the chain and restart the timer. When the timer falls off you will be rewarded for the size of your chain.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and what is observable (I check the amount of XP per group of monsters I get from time to time, to see what is effectively farmable), there are none of these bonuses that you speak of. Monsters of a certain type and level always seem to give a fixed amount of XP, disregarding your level.